# Why am I being asked to completely merge 4 rooms?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In fallout shelter, on android, one of the objectives that may come up is to **completely merge four rooms**. However, as stated in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224501/how-many-rooms-can-merge-together), you can only merge a maximum of three rooms together.

Is this a bug, a typo, or am I missing something entirely?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **merge room objective** is instructing you to merge 3 rooms together a particular amount of times.

For example, if the objective reads "merge four rooms", it means to **merge three rooms, four times**.

It does not matter what type of rooms you make, as long as they are merges of three separate rooms.

Also keep in mind that rooms will not merge together if they are different levels. For example, if you upgrade your water treatment plant, it will not merge with a joining water treatment plant, until the second plant is upgraded to the same level.

[image: An example of multiple merged rooms]

Comment: You don't need to merge a full trio of rooms. In fact, that would give you two merges for the purposes of the quest/mission/objective

Comment: @Dallium, changed the post to clarify a bit better, but it **is** asking for a three room merge. I've already personally confirmed that only a three-room merge counts towards completion of this objective.

Comment: No, you don't. Merging two rooms is fine. I've completed this objective numerous times.

Comment: @Dallium, then it is a different objective you are thinking of. I have watched the objective lay dormant merging two rooms, and increment on merging the third room.

Comment: No, I'm not. I'll provide screenshots when I reproduce it

Comment: Your fine to do so, @Dallium, but given that **merging two rooms together did not fix the problem**, I don't see the point. Maybe someone else can clarify between the two

Comment: @Timelord64 this is almost entirely accurate, except that it should treat **any** room merge as a merge for the purposes of the objective, not just from size two to size three. If that's not happening, it's a bug as it's working for me on iOS.

Comment: I can confirm @Dallium's claim. I'm at 3/4 of that objective and have only merged single rooms into double ones. I *did* have triple rooms before getting that objective though, so it's possible either side is experiencing a bug. The question is, which one is the bug and which one isn't.

Comment: @Nolonar, is this on android or iOS?

Comment: @Timelord64. In my case Android.

Comment: I presume, in that case, that it is a different objective that counts merging any room. As I have previously stated, I merged two rooms, nothing. Merged into the three rooms, and popped. I suspect that there would be an objective for just performing a plain room merge. I realised as soon as I achieved the three room merge that the objective was asking for a "complete merge", or something of that like, suggesting the maximum size possible.

Comment: The objective I have currently is "Merge 5 pairs of rooms together". This will advance from merging two single rooms together. I have yet to merge a two and a three to confirm if that moves further. I am happy to believe there might be one that involves triples of rooms but thought I'd clarify the wording for the two room one.

Comment: Yeah i have had the two room one pop up before

Answer (score 0):

Build a Power Plant three rooms wide. Upgrade it all the way.
Build a Water Plant three rooms wide. Upgrade it all the way.
Build a Diner three rooms wide. Upgrade it all the way.
Build a Hospital / Science Lab / Storage Room / Radio Room.
Or ANY three rooms that can be merged together.
Do that four times. 
Boom. Objective finished. [Merge Three Rooms; Four Times]